# How to position multiple image on the same plot using a pixel matrix

Tags: r, image, plot, machine-learning

I am trying to illustrate 100 random training example on the same plot using the kaggle dataset you can found here : https://www.kaggle.com/c/digit-recognizer/data.

I am able to plot one after the other the number but not on the same plot :

```
  par(mfrow=c(5,5))

for(i in sample(2:length(data),100,replace=FALSE)){      
    dat <- matrix(as.numeric(data[i,1:784]/256),ncol=28,nrow=28,byrow=TRUE)
    image(dat, axes=TRUE,col=grey(seq(0,1,length=256)))
}
```

What I wanna do is something like this:

[image: Plot digits]

I am not able to figure out how to specify the location of each pixel....

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick solution would be to set margins (`mar`) to `0` using `par`:

```
par(mfrow=c(5,5), mar=c(0,0,0,0))

for(i in sample(2:length(data),100,replace=FALSE)){      
    dat <- matrix(as.numeric(data[i,1:784]/256),ncol=28,nrow=28,byrow=TRUE)
    image(dat, axes=FALSE,col=grey(seq(0,1,length=256)))
}
```

If you want border on the outside, set `oma` in `par` to values >0. E.g.

```
par(mfrow=c(5,5), mar=c(0,0,0,0), oma=c(2,2,2,2))
```