# How to plot an RGB image using the image() function from a 3D array?

Tags: r, image, image-processing, plot

I have an array with dimension (28,28,3) height, width, depth. Each depth is one of the RGB channels. The values are between 0 and 1.

I want to use the image() function to plot the image. The z argument is a matrix. How can I convert the array into a matrix in order to be able to plot?

My final goal is to have something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43327811/how-to-position-multiple-image-on-the-same-plot-using-a-pixel-matrix) but with color images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach is with `rasterImage`

```
set.seed(3)
data <- replicate(4,array(data = runif(28*28*3,0,1),
                          dim = c(28,28,3)), simplify = FALSE)

par(mfrow=c(2, 2), mar=c(0, 0, 3, 0))
sapply(seq_along(data), function(x){
  plot.new()
  rasterImage(data[[x]], xleft = 0, xright = 1,
            ytop = 0, ybottom = 1, interpolate = FALSE)
  title(paste0("Plot ",x))
})
```

[image]

Comment: Because I would like to plot several images as a grid and add labels above each.

Comment: OK, I added a `rasterImage` solution.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with `graphics::image` is that it will not plot your 3D array as a colour image. It plots a matrix as a heatmap.

Let's take a colorful patterned image:

```
R <- matrix(rep(sin(seq(0, 2*pi, length.out = 31))^2, length.out = 900), nrow = 30)
G <- matrix(rep(cos(seq(0, 2*pi, length.out = 15))^2, length.out = 900), nrow = 30)
B <- matrix(rep(sin(seq(pi, 2*pi, length.out = 30))^2, length.out = 900), nrow = 30)

my_img <- c(R, G, B)
dim(my_img) <- c(30, 30, 3)
```

Now if I plot this with `raster` as @IanCampbell suggests, I get my desired image:

```
plot(raster::as.raster(my_img))
```

[image]

whereas if I plot one layer (here the red channel) using `image`, I get a heatmap:

```
image(R)
```

[image]

If you *really* want to use `image`, then you would have to average all your layers, but then you lose colour information, and still get a heat map:

```
image((R + B + G)/3)
```

[image]

So the bottom line is that if you want to plot a colour image, then *image* is not the function you are looking for. There are lots of ways to plot multiple colour images in a single R window, so saying that you have to use `image` because you need to plot a grid of images just isn't true.

For example:

```
grid.arrange(rasterGrob(my_img),   rasterGrob(1-my_img),
             rasterGrob(1-my_img), rasterGrob(my_img), ncol = 2)
```

[image]

Comment: Your sample data is so much better than mine. I'm going to save that for later.

Answer (score 0):

With the raster package you can do

```
R <- matrix(rep(sin(seq(0, 2*pi, length.out = 31))^2, length.out = 900), nrow = 30)
G <- matrix(rep(cos(seq(0, 2*pi, length.out = 15))^2, length.out = 900), nrow = 30)
B <- matrix(rep(sin(seq(pi, 2*pi, length.out = 30))^2, length.out = 900), nrow = 30)

my_img <- c(R, G, B)
dim(my_img) <- c(30, 30, 3)

library(raster)
b <- brick(my_img)
crs(b) <- "+proj=tmerc"
plotRGB(b, scale=1)
# or
plotRGB(b, scale=1, interpolate=TRUE)
```